# How to speed up reading/scanning mass files for an exact keyword match

Tags: python

So ive looked on google and the only results i get is "reading large files", not much about how to speed up reading multiple files.

I have a sound-alias-keyword. This keyword will need to be scanned in up to 128 files
and i could have up to 1,600 keywords to scan for in said files.

So as you can see thats a lot of opening/reading. And its loading time is very slow. I cant have it be this slow for my program. I need to reduce the load time by 10 fold.

So i have this code snippet which reads files line by line and if a mention of the keyword is in said line then it will do an exact-match check.

```
for file in weapon_files:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as weapon_file:
        for m in weapon_file:
            if sAlias in m:
                t = re.compile(fr'\b{sAlias}\b')
                result = t.search(m)
                if result:                         
                    called_file_.append(''.join(f"root{file[len(WAW_ROOT_DIR):]}"))
```

I then thought id try and see if i could speed things up by turning the file into a string. Do a basic scan to see if theres any mention and if so, then do an exact-match search. But this approach didnt speed it up by anything worth caring about.

```
for file in weapon_files:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as weapon_file:
        w = weapon_file.read()
    if sAlias in w:
        t = re.compile(fr'\b{sAlias}\b')
        result = t.search(w)
        if result: 
            called_file_.append(''.join(f"root{file[len(WAW_ROOT_DIR):]}"))
```

I then thought id just open each file, turn it into a string and then append all the file-strings together, check for any mention, then do an exact-match search. Which did actually reduce the loading time but then i realised i cant use that approach as the whole point of scanning these files for an exact-keyword-match is to then store the matched-file-directory into a list. This approach removes any chance of that.

```
weaponString = ""
for file in weapon_files:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as weapon_file:
        e = weapon_file.read()
    weaponString += e

if sAlias in weaponString:
    t = re.compile(fr'\b{sAlias}\b')
    result = t.search(weaponString)
    if result:
        called_file_.append(''.join(f"root{file[len(WAW_ROOT_DIR):]}"))
```

This is what the files look like.
It may also be worth mentioning these files have no .extension, but i dont think thats an issue as python can still read these files just fine.

```
WEAPONFILE\displayName\WEAPON_30CAL\modeName\\playerAnimType\smg\altWeapon\\AIOverlayDescription\WEAPON_SUBMACHINEGUNNER\weaponType\bullet\weaponClass\mg\penetrateType\large\impactType\bullet_large\inventoryType\primary\fireType\Full Auto\clipType\lmg\twoHanded\1\rifleBullet\0\armorPiercing\0\boltAction\0\aimDownSight\1\rechamberWhileAds\1\noADSAutoReload\0\noPartialReload\0\segmentedReload\0\adsFire\0\noAdsWhenMagEmpty\0\avoidDropCleanup\0\enhanced\0\bayonet\0\cancelAutoHolsterWhenEmpty\0\suppressAmmoReserveDisplay\0\laserSightDuringNightvision\0\blocksProne\0\silenced\0\mountableWeapon\0\autoAimRange\1200\aimAssistRange\3200\aimAssistRangeAds\3200\enemyCrosshairRange\720\crosshairColorChange\1\moveSpeedScale\0.75\adsMoveSpeedScale\0.75\sprintDurationScale\0.75\gunMaxPitch\6\gunMaxYaw\6\lowAmmoWarningThreshold\0.33\ammoName\30cal\maxAmmo\500\startAmmo\500\clipName\30cal\clipSize\125\shotCount\1\dropAmmoMin\200\dropAmmoMax\250\reloadAmmoAdd\0\reloadStartAdd\0\damage\130\minDamage\90\meleeDamage\150\maxDamageRange\1024\minDamageRange\2400\playerDamage\70\locNone\1\locHelmet\3\locHead\3\locNeck\1\locTorsoUpper\1\locTorsoLower\1\locRightArmUpper\1\locRightArmLower\1\locRightHand\1\locLeftArmUpper\1\locLeftArmLower\1\locLeftHand\1\locRightLegUpper\1\locRightLegLower\1\locRightFoot\1\locLeftLegUpper\1\locLeftLegLower\1\locLeftFoot\1\locGun\0\fireTime\0.096\fireDelay\0\meleeTime\0.5\meleeChargeTime\1\meleeDelay\0.05\meleeChargeDelay\0.15\reloadTime\7\reloadEmptyTime\6\reloadEmptyAddTime\0\reloadStartTime\0\reloadEndTime\0\reloadAddTime\4.75\reloadStartAddTime\0\rechamberTime\0.1\rechamberBoltTime\0\dropTime\0.83\raiseTime\0.9\altDropTime\0.7\altRaiseTime\0\quickDropTime\0.25\quickRaiseTime\0.25\firstRaiseTime\1.5\emptyDropTime\0.5\emptyRaiseTime\0.5\sprintInTime\0.5\sprintLoopTime\0.8\sprintOutTime\0.2\deployTime\0.5\breakdownTime\0.5\nightVisionWearTime\0.5\nightVisionWearTimeFadeOutEnd\0\nightVisionWearTimePowerUp\0\nightVisionRemoveTime\0.5\nightVisionRemoveTimePowerDown\0\nightVisionRemoveTimeFadeInStart\0\standMoveF\0\standMoveR\0\standMoveU\-2\standRotP\0\standRotY\0\standRotR\0\standMoveMinSpeed\0\standRotMinSpeed\0\posMoveRate\8\posRotRate\8\sprintOfsF\1\sprintOfsR\-2\sprintOfsU\-1\sprintRotP\10\sprintRotY\45\sprintRotR\-20\sprintBobH\8\sprintBobV\6\sprintScale\0.9\duckedSprintOfsF\2\duckedSprintOfsR\-1\duckedSprintOfsU\0\duckedSprintRotP\10\duckedSprintRotY\25\duckedSprintRotR\-20\duckedSprintBobH\2\duckedSprintBobV\3\duckedSprintScale\0.8\duckedMoveF\0\duckedMoveR\0\duckedMoveU\-1.5\duckedRotP\0\duckedRotY\0\duckedRotR\0\duckedOfsF\-0.5\duckedOfsR\0.25\duckedOfsU\-0.6\duckedMoveMinSpeed\0\duckedRotMinSpeed\0\proneMoveF\-160\proneMoveR\-75\proneMoveU\-120\proneRotP\0\proneRotY\300\proneRotR\-300\proneOfsF\0\proneOfsR\0.5\proneOfsU\-1\posProneMoveRate\10\posProneRotRate\10\proneMoveMinSpeed\0\proneRotMinSpeed\0\hipIdleAmount\30\adsIdleAmount\28\hipIdleSpeed\1\adsIdleSpeed\0.9\idleCrouchFactor\0.75\idleProneFactor\0.4\adsSpread\0\adsAimPitch\0\adsTransInTime\0.22\adsTransOutTime\0.4\adsTransBlendTime\0.1\adsReloadTransTime\0.3\adsCrosshairInFrac\1\adsCrosshairOutFrac\0.2\adsZoomFov\50\adsZoomInFrac\0.7\adsZoomOutFrac\0.4\adsBobFactor\0\adsViewBobMult\0.25\adsViewErrorMin\0\adsViewErrorMax\0\hipSpreadStandMin\4\hipSpreadDuckedMin\3.5\hipSpreadProneMin\3\hipSpreadMax\10\hipSpreadDuckedMax\8\hipSpreadProneMax\6\hipSpreadFireAdd\0.6\hipSpreadTurnAdd\0\hipSpreadMoveAdd\5\hipSpreadDecayRate\4\hipSpreadDuckedDecay\1.05\hipSpreadProneDecay\1.1\hipGunKickReducedKickBullets\0\hipGunKickReducedKickPercent\0\hipGunKickPitchMin\5\hipGunKickPitchMax\-15\hipGunKickYawMin\5\hipGunKickYawMax\-5\hipGunKickAccel\800\hipGunKickSpeedMax\2000\hipGunKickSpeedDecay\16\hipGunKickStaticDecay\20\adsGunKickReducedKickBullets\0\adsGunKickReducedKickPercent\75\adsGunKickPitchMin\5\adsGunKickPitchMax\15\adsGunKickYawMin\-5\adsGunKickYawMax\10\adsGunKickAccel\800\adsGunKickSpeedMax\2000\adsGunKickSpeedDecay\32\adsGunKickStaticDecay\40\hipViewKickPitchMin\70\hipViewKickPitchMax\80\hipViewKickYawMin\-30\hipViewKickYawMax\-60\hipViewKickCenterSpeed\1500\adsViewKickPitchMin\45\adsViewKickPitchMax\55\adsViewKickYawMin\-70\adsViewKickYawMax\70\adsViewKickCenterSpeed\1800\swayMaxAngle\4\swayLerpSpeed\6\swayPitchScale\0.1\swayYawScale\0.1\swayHorizScale\0.2\swayVertScale\0.2\swayShellShockScale\5\adsSwayMaxAngle\4\adsSwayLerpSpeed\6\adsSwayPitchScale\0.1\adsSwayYawScale\0\adsSwayHorizScale\0.08\adsSwayVertScale\0.1\fightDist\720\maxDist\340\aiVsAiAccuracyGraph\thompson.accu\aiVsPlayerAccuracyGraph\light_machine_gun.accu\reticleCenter\\reticleSide\reticle_side_small\reticleCenterSize\4\reticleSideSize\8\reticleMinOfs\0\hipReticleSidePos\0\adsOverlayShader\\adsOverlayShaderLowRes\\adsOverlayReticle\none\adsOverlayWidth\220\adsOverlayHeight\220\gunModel\viewmodel_usa_30cal_lmg\gunModel2\\gunModel3\\gunModel4\\gunModel5\\gunModel6\\gunModel7\\gunModel8\\gunModel9\\gunModel10\\gunModel11\\gunModel12\\gunModel13\\gunModel14\\gunModel15\\gunModel16\\handModel\viewmodel_hands_no_model\worldModel\weapon_usa_30cal_lmg\worldModel2\\worldModel3\\worldModel4\\worldModel5\\worldModel6\\worldModel7\\worldModel8\\worldModel9\\worldModel10\\worldModel11\\worldModel12\\worldModel13\\worldModel14\\worldModel15\\worldModel16\\worldClipModel\\knifeModel\viewmodel_usa_kbar_knife\worldKnifeModel\weapon_usa_kbar_knife\idleAnim\viewmodel_30cal_idle\emptyIdleAnim\viewmodel_30cal_empty_idle\fireAnim\viewmodel_30cal_fire\lastShotAnim\viewmodel_30cal_lastshot\rechamberAnim\\meleeAnim\viewmodel_knife_slash\meleeChargeAnim\viewmodel_knife_stick\reloadAnim\viewmodel_30cal_partial_reload\reloadEmptyAnim\viewmodel_30cal_reload\reloadStartAnim\\reloadEndAnim\\raiseAnim\viewmodel_30cal_pullout\dropAnim\viewmodel_30cal_putaway\firstRaiseAnim\viewmodel_30cal_first_raise\altRaiseAnim\\altDropAnim\\quickRaiseAnim\viewmodel_30cal_pullout_fast\quickDropAnim\viewmodel_30cal_putaway_fast\emptyRaiseAnim\viewmodel_30cal_pullout_empty\emptyDropAnim\viewmodel_30cal_putaway_empty\sprintInAnim\\sprintLoopAnim\\sprintOutAnim\\nightVisionWearAnim\\nightVisionRemoveAnim\\adsFireAnim\viewmodel_30cal_ADS_fire\adsLastShotAnim\viewmodel_30cal_ADS_lastshot\adsRechamberAnim\\adsUpAnim\viewmodel_30cal_ADS_up\adsDownAnim\viewmodel_30cal_ADS_down\deployAnim\\breakdownAnim\\viewFlashEffect\weapon/muzzleflashes/fx_30cal_bulletweap_view\worldFlashEffect\weapon/muzzleflashes/fx_30cal_bulletweap\viewShellEjectEffect\weapon/shellejects/fx_heavy_link_view\worldShellEjectEffect\weapon/shellejects/fx_heavy\viewLastShotEjectEffect\\worldLastShotEjectEffect\\worldClipDropEffect\\pickupSound\weap_pickup\pickupSoundPlayer\weap_pickup_plr\ammoPickupSound\ammo_pickup\ammoPickupSoundPlayer\ammo_pickup_plr\breakdownSound\\breakdownSoundPlayer\\deploySound\\deploySoundPlayer\\finishDeploySound\\finishDeploySoundPlayer\\fireSound\weap_30cal_fire\fireSoundPlayer\weap_30cal_fire_plr\lastShotSound\weap_30cal_fire\lastShotSoundPlayer\weap_30cal_fire_plr\emptyFireSound\dryfire_rifle\emptyFireSoundPlayer\dryfire_rifle_plr\crackSound\\whizbySound\\meleeSwipeSound\melee_swing\meleeSwipeSoundPlayer\melee_swing_plr\meleeHitSound\melee_hit\meleeMissSound\\rechamberSound\\rechamberSoundPlayer\\reloadSound\gr_30cal_3p_full\reloadSoundPlayer\\reloadEmptySound\gr_30cal_3p_full\reloadEmptySoundPlayer\\reloadStartSound\\reloadStartSoundPlayer\\reloadEndSound\\reloadEndSoundPlayer\\altSwitchSound\\altSwitchSoundPlayer\\raiseSound\weap_raise\raiseSoundPlayer\weap_raise_plr\firstRaiseSound\weap_raise\firstRaiseSoundPlayer\weap_raise_plr\putawaySound\weap_putaway\putawaySoundPlayer\weap_putaway_plr\nightVisionWearSound\\nightVisionWearSoundPlayer\\nightVisionRemoveSound\\nightVisionRemoveSoundPlayer\\standMountedWeapdef\\crouchMountedWeapdef\\proneMountedWeapdef\\mountedModel\\hudIcon\hud_icon_30cal\killIcon\hud_icon_30cal\dpadIcon\\ammoCounterIcon\\hudIconRatio\4:1\killIconRatio\4:1\dpadIconRatio\4:1\ammoCounterIconRatio\4:1\ammoCounterClip\Beltfed\flipKillIcon\1\fireRumble\defaultweapon_fire\meleeImpactRumble\defaultweapon_melee\adsDofStart\0\adsDofEnd\7.5\hideTags\\notetrackSoundMap\gr_30cal_start_plr gr_30cal_start_plr 
gr_30cal_open_plr gr_30cal_open_plr 
gr_30cal_grab_belt_plr gr_30cal_grab_belt_plr 
gr_30cal_belt_remove_plr gr_30cal_belt_remove_plr 
gr_30cal_belt_raise_plr gr_30cal_belt_raise_plr 
gr_30cal_belt_contact_plr gr_30cal_belt_contact_plr 
gr_30cal_belt_press_plr gr_30cal_belt_press_plr 
gr_30cal_close_plr gr_30cal_close_plr 
gr_30cal_charge_plr gr_30cal_charge_plr 
gr_30cal_ammo_toss_plr gr_30cal_ammo_toss_plr 
gr_30cal_charge_release_plr gr_30cal_charge_release_plr
gr_30cal_lid_bonk_plr gr_30cal_lid_bonk_plr
knife_stab_plr knife_stab_plr
knife_pull_plr knife_pull_plr
Knife_slash_plr Knife_slash_plr
gr_mg_deploy_start gr_mg_deploy_start 
gr_mg_deploy_end gr_mg_deploy_end 
gr_mg_break_down gr_mg_break_down 
gr_30cal_tap_plr gr_30cal_tap_plr
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Turning the file into a string will use a large amount of memory and probably be quite slow too due to the allocations. It's overall a worse way of doing things

Comment: You might consider a program like “grep” for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching line by line, you can search the entire file at once. I have included a code example below, which searches one file for multiple keywords and prints the keywords found.

```py
keywords = ["gr_30cal_open_plr", "gr_mg_deploy_end", "wontfindthis"]
with open("test.txt") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    # Search the file for each keyword.
    keywords_found = {keyword for keyword in keywords if keyword in contents}

if keywords_found:
    print("This file contains the following keywords:")
    print(keywords_found)
else:
    print("This file did not contain any keywords.")
```

I'll explain the code. `f.read()` will read the file contents. Then I use a set comprehension to get all of the keywords found in the file. I use a set because that will keep only the unique keywords -- I assume you don't need to know how many times a keyword appears in the file. (A set comprehension is similar to a list comprehension, but it creates a set.) Testing whether the keyword is in the file is as easy as `keyword in contents`.

I used your sample file contents and duplicated it multiple times so the file contained `45,252,362` lines (1.8 GB). And my code above took less than 1 second.

Comment: This way well be the fix im looking for (ty) however this approach is different to mine so i just need to see if i can implement this to my method before marking this as the best answer.

Comment: rather than having- This file contains the following keywords:

is it possible to have- This keyword contains the following files:

??

your code is definitely quick the only issue is that my method is basically setting a qtablewidget row by row, by looping through each unique keyword. thats why my previous approaches show me searching through 54 files 1,279 times. coz my loop is going keyword by keyword.

each row contains other things like sound path, sound name, if called, qpushbtn so im not reli looking to change the whole method but yh at this point im struggling to use ur code.

Comment: i think the only way i can implement it is by somehow achieving this: 
This keyword contains the following files:

instead of your example:
This file contains the following keywords:

Comment: Basically all of this is for the "if called?" column in my qtablewidget.
This program answers the question "should this sound be loaded?"
So what i do is scan all these file for a keyword and then temporarily store all these files directories in a list and then add that list to the cell in the table to say that "yes, this sound should be loaded coz its mentioned in all of these files",
else: ill add a string of "No" to the cell informing the user that they can go ahead and hit the disable sound btn.

Comment: Note:
exactly what keywords match, does not matter.

All that matters is knowing if theres a match and then storing all the files said keyword was mentioned in.

Maybe a dictionary would be handy for this actually coz then in my loop i can then quickly search the dict for the key(keyword i,.e sound alias) and then the dict value would have all the files directories since my loop iterates through each sound alias anyway.

Comment: Based on your last comment, I would go with a dictionary. The keys can be the keywords, and the values can be a list of the files that contains that keyword. I would still suggest iterating over each file, because then you will minimize how many times you need to read files. If you iterate over keywords, you are reading each file as many times as you have keywords.

Comment: indeed i completely agree. i actually think i just managed to get your approach working with the use of a dictionary. my only issue now is to fix the file-keyword-matching as its matching keywords that arent exact ones but i think this is a case of just using re.compile & re.search like i have in my above examples.

Comment: so i think i just need to edit this-
keywords_found = {keyword for keyword in keywords if keyword in contents}
to look for an Exact-keyword-match and then it should be good to go :)

Comment: Is there any way to turn this into a set comprehension?

keywords_found = set()
for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in contents:
        t = re.compile(fr'\b{keyword}\b')
        result = t.search(contents)
        if result:
            keywords_found.add(keyword)

Comment: You could, but I wouldn’t recommend it tbh. That would be a long comprehension and wouldn’t be readable. Your current solution is best imho

Comment: arent comprehensions faster though? it'll still be handy to have the set comprehension and id just keep the current approach commented out so i can read it lmao

but either way tyvm for your help. appreciated.

Comment: They’re not necessarily faster. Just syntactic sugar :)

Answer (score 0):

well you can use `multiprocessing` to speed up your work, but I don't think it is the best way, but well I am sharing the code so you can try it for yourself and see if that work for you or not.

```
  import multiprocessing
    
  def process(file):
      with open(file, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as weapon_file:
      for m in weapon_file:
          if sAlias in m:
             t = re.compile(fr'\b{sAlias}\b')
             result = t.search(m)
             if result:                        
                called_file_.append 
                          (''.join(f"root{file[len(WAW_ROOT_DIR):]}"))
    
  p = multiprocessing.Pool()
  for file in weapon_files:
       # now launch a process for each file.
       # The result will be approximately one process per CPU core available.
       p.apply_async(process, [file]) 
    
  p.close()
  p.join() # Wait for all child processes to be closed.
```

hope it helps.